# Cannot create profile automatically with django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm new to Django and try to create a userprofile along with any user that registers through django-registration module. Here is my UserProfile module:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    User.profile = property(lambda u:UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=u)[0])

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I have also this in settings.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.UserProfile'
```

When users are created they are refered to this view to fill their profile form:

```
def add_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit = False)
            f.username_id= request.user.id
            form.save()    
            return render_to_response('userprofile/ok.html',
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
        else:
            print form.errors

    else:

        form = UserProfileForm()    
    return render_to_response('userprofile/add_profile.html', {'form': form}, 
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but when they submit the form, they get this error:

```
TypeError at /profile/add/sara/
add_profile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

I know that there are many similar questions on SO and I tried many of the suggestions but none work for me. So appreciate your hints

Comment: Is the add_profile method part of django registration or is something you wrote?

Comment: @cdvv7788 add_profile is in view.py of my own module i.e UserProfile.

Comment: Issue is your url. Your method is receiving only a request, not an username.

Comment: @cdvv7788 You are right. It was actually a views problem. Many thanks for the hint.